# libvirt hot unplug cpu

Tags: libvirt, virsh, vcpu

I'm currently working with libvirt. after i reduce the number of vcpu cores with below command, the operation will be completed successfully. i should also mention that my current and max vcpus is 4, before this command.

```
virsh setvcpus instance-000000xx 2 --config
```

after this command i rebooted the vm so the changes would apply. after rebooting i changed my vcpus to 4 again.

```
virsh setvcpus instance-000000xx 4 --config --live
```

the problem is after i change vcpus live to 2, the VM will shut down, like it crashes after this operation. virsh also show below error.

> error: operation failed: vcpu unplug request timeout

how can i unplug my vcpus live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your VM is crashing, that's a bug somewhere, probably in qemu. I suggest filing a bug with whatever linux distribution you are using.